# Prove $\cos(x) \geq 0 $ with $x \in [0 , \frac{\pi}{2}$]

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

Let $x \in [0 , \frac{\pi}{2}$]. How can i show that $\forall x: \cos(x) \geq 0 $. I'm searching for a prove without derivation... Maybe some estimates of the power series representation of cosinus?

Cosinus/Sinus is defined by the Powerseries and $\pi$ is defined $\sin(\pi) = 0$ with $\pi \in (0,4)$

Comment: If you define $\cos(x)$ in the classical way, through geometry, that's obvious. If you define $\cos$ and $\sin$ by their power series, it's unclear how you want to define $\pi$, or what the number known from geometry has to do with those power series. If you define $\pi$ from the first positive zeroes of the series, it's trivial, again. So how are your definitions?

Comment: @Anna Saabel isn't it by definition? why you are searching sor other methods?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your definition of $\cos x$, and of $\pi$. The usual definition  for $\cos$ uses the Maclaurin series $$\cos x := \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^i}{(2i)!}x^{2k},$$
and the definition of $\pi$ can be taken as the smallest $x > 0$ such that $\sin x = 0$, (where $\sin$ is defined similarly as a Maclaurin series). With these definitions, one may differentiate the terms of $\cos x$ term by term to get that $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(\cos x) = -\sin x$. It can also be shown that both these functions are continuous.

Now it is easy to show that $-\sin 1 < 0$. Since $ x = \pi$ is the smallest positive zero of $\sin x$, and $\sin x$ is continuous in $(0,\pi)$, it follows that $-\sin x < 0$ for all $x \in (0, \pi)$. Therefore the derivative of $\cos x$ is negative for $x \in (0, \pi)$. This means that $\cos x$ has a downhill slope for $x\in(0,\pi)$.

It is also easy to show that $\cos 0 = 1$, and that $\cos \frac{\pi}{2} = 0$. Since the slope is always downhill between these two values, then $\cos$ must always be positive in $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.

This is only an idea of the proof, which needs to be backed up by several theorems, one of which is the fact that if $f: A\to\mathbb R$ is continuous on $[a,b]\subseteq A$ and $b$ is the smallest value on $[a,b]$ such that $f(x) = 0$, then $f(x) > 0$ for all $x\in[a,b)$.

Comment: "The usual definition for $cos$ uses the Maclaurin series". I disagree on the fact that this is the **usual** way of defining the cosine function.

Comment: @b00nheT Well in analysis it certainly is, unless you prefer the definition via differential equations (which when solved via the power series method gives the same Maclaurin's series).

Comment: @b00nheT what other way would it be defined?

Comment: The edit by the OP says the series is what is wanted here.  Other possible definitions for cosine: (1) a particular solution of a differential equation $y''+y=0$. (2) inverse function of a certain integral, taken as the definition of arccosine.